# SVG text display issue in Safari

Tags: svg, safari

I have an SVG image which I am trying to display in an HTML page. When this is displayed in Safari, the text overlaps with each other as seen below:

[image]

When I display this svg in Chrome, the text appears better. You can see the 'One Center' text is not overlapped.

[image]

The SVG code for these 4 lines is as below:

[image]

Here is the markup:

```
<svg:g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="">
<svg:text transform=" scale(1, -1)" xml:space="preserve">
    <svg:tspan font-family="Helvetica" font-size="8px" y="-712.4" x="22.7 24.924 30.724 35.628 42.732 47.18 51.628 56.076 58.724 60.948 66.748 71.196 76.1 78.3 82.748 84.972 90.772 95.676 102.78 109.884 114.788 119.692 121.892 126.34 130.788 133.436 135.636 140.54 145.444 149.892" font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
        ABC DEF JHK
    </svg:tspan>
</svg:text>
```

```
<svg:g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="">
<svg:text transform=" scale(1, -1)" xml:space="preserve">
    <svg:tspan font-family="Helvetica" font-size="8px" y="-712.4" x="152 158.648 163.096 168 172.448 177.352 181.8 188.904 193.352 198.256 200.904 203.128 208.032 212.936" font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
        Management LLC
    </svg:tspan>
</svg:text>
```

```
<svg:g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="">
<svg:text transform=" scale(1, -1)" xml:space="preserve">
    <svg:tspan font-family="Helvetica" font-size="8px" y="-703.4" x="22.7 24.924 31.124 36.028 40.476 42.7 48.5 53.404 60.508 64.956 69.404 73.852 76.5 78.724 84.524 88.972 93.876 96.524 100.972" font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(0,0,0)"> 
        One Center
    </svg:tspan>
</svg:text>
```

Any ideas on why Safari would render it badly compared to Chrome and if anything can be done to correct this?

Comment: I have added markup for the first and the second line.

Comment: If I only set the starting x co-ordinate instead of passing the co-ordinate for each character, it works and Safari renders each line of text correctly.

Comment: A fiddle to reproduce maybe on chrome? :) Too bad I don't have a VM or a mac to test it anything on Safari...